# Can't sign on to site in Ubuntu Phone browser

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser

I tried to sign in to my owncloud machine through the web interface. The browser allows me to enter a username and password, but hitting the Return key does nothing.

I tried using a Bluetooth keyboard and had the same problem.

Comment: Is there a sign-in button you can press? Most of the time on mobile, hitting Done or Return doesn't actually submit.

Comment: Nope, no Submit type button.  I think my best bet is to add one.  I looked through the code and discovered it's actually pretty difficult to find what creates the owncloud sign in page.  I thought it would be as simple as hand editing index.php or something, but no such luck.